# Show that $\frac{xy}{z} + \frac{xz}{y} + \frac{yz}{x} \geq x+y+z $ by considering homogeneity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Well, I'm preparing for an undergrad competition that is held in April and because of that I've been trying to solve the inequalities I find on the internet. I found this problem:
$$\displaystyle  \frac{xy}{z} + \frac{xz}{y} + \frac{yz}{x} \geq x+y+z \text{ for all }  x,y,z \in \mathbb{R^+}$$

It's easy to show that this inequality holds by applying the AM-GM inequality three times like the following:

$$ \frac{xy}{z} + \frac{xz}{y} \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac{xy}{z} \cdot\frac{xz}{y}} = 2x$$
$$ \frac{xy}{z} + \frac{yz}{x} \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac{xy}{z} \cdot\frac{yz}{x}} = 2y$$
$$ \frac{zy}{x} + \frac{xz}{y} \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac{zy}{x} \cdot\frac{xz}{y}} = 2z$$

Then summing these inequalities and canceling a factor of $2$ at the end will give us the desired inequality.

But if you look at the problem from another point of view, if we substitute $x'=\lambda x$, $y'=\lambda y$ and $z' = \lambda z$ the inequality stays the same. So, I was wondering if there could be another way of solving this inequality and the inequalities that are homogenous like this one in a more systematic way that could be applied to a broader range of problems.

I decided to add a constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ to the problem because the inequality in the problem could be thought of as a function in the three variables $x,y,z$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, it's sufficient to study this function on the unit sphere because homogeneity allows us to define it for other points of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but I have no idea how this could lead me anywhere.

Comment: What do you get if you add your 3 equations together?  Never mind, you already did that.

Comment: You can constrain $(x,y,z)$ to any surface that intersects every ray from the origin into the first octant. In particular, you could assume that $xyz=1$, then prove $\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\le x+y+z$. (Not that this is better than other solutions given, but it's good to know.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to take advantage of the homogeneity.

By symmetry and homogeneity, one can assume without loss of generality that $z=\min(x,y,z)$ and that $z=1$. This reduces the problem to the following.

Proposition: If $x\ge1$ and $y\ge1$, then $\displaystyle \frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}+xy \ge 1+x+y$.

Proof: Assume that $x\ge1$ and $y\ge1$. Then

$$x y=((x-1)+1)((y-1)+1)=$$ 
$$(x-1)+(y-1)+1+(x-1)(y-1)\ge x+y-1\textrm,$$

because $(x-1)(y-1)$ is non-negative.

The sum of a positive real number and its reciprocal is always at least 2, so

$$\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x} \ge 2\textrm.$$

Combining these two inequalities gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks. This is a clear answer. I particularly liked the $z=1$ restriction that you forced because of homogeneity. It simplified the problem nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your question, but I did find another rather simple way to prove it

Given $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$,

\begin{align}
0 &\leq (xy - xz)^2 \\
&= (xy)^2 + (xz)^2 - 2x^2yz \\
2x^2yz &\leq (xy)^2 + (xz)^2
\end{align}
and similarly for $2y^2xz$ and $2z^2xy$. Then adding, and dividing by 2 gives
$$
x^2yz + y^2xz + z^2xy \leq (xy)^2 + (xz)^2 + (yz)^2
$$
then dividing by $xyz$ on both sides gives
$$
x + y + z \leq \frac{xy}{z} + \frac{xz}{y} + \frac{yz}{x}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any particular advantage to adding a constraint in this case, (or in general), as the original inequality is proved easily enough as you noticed.

Another way, it is direct from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that:
$$LHS^2 = \left(\frac{xy}{z} + \frac{xz}{y} + \frac{yz}{x} \right)\left(\frac{xz}{y} + \frac{yz}{x} + \frac{xy}{z} \right) \ge (x+y+z)^2 = RHS^2$$

OTOH, adding the constraint $xyz = 1$ to the original problem, gives the equivalent inequality:
$$\frac1{x^2} + \frac1{y^2} + \frac1{z^2} \ge \frac1{xy}+\frac1{yz} + \frac1{zx}$$
which is obvious by Rearrangement Inequality, and seems equally easy compared to AM-GM or C-S approach.

I am sure there are many more ways to show the inequality in homogeneous form or with a suitable constraint.  There may be other problems where one approach is preferable, though in general it seems more of personal preference rather than either approach being easier / more systematic.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please explain why we can add the restriction $xyz=1$? I can't see how homogeneity can justify it.

Comment: Let $xyz=p^3>0$. Then we can scale each variable down by $p$, and the inequality is unchanged.

Comment: Yes, I first thought of something like that but why $p=1$? Pardon me if what I'm asking is too obvious.

Comment: We can set the product to any positive real, $1$ is just convenient. Once you establish the inequality / equation is homogeneous, there are many kinds of constraints that you can set by appropriate scaling.

Comment: Note, given any set of variables that satisfy the original inequality, we can find a corresponding scaled version that in addition satisfies $xyz=1$ or $x+y+z=1$ or $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ etc...

Comment: OK. So, a bit more rigorously we could say that given any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ we could choose $\lambda=\sqrt[3]{xyz}$ and then we set $x'=\lambda x$, $y'=\lambda y$ and $z'= \lambda z$ which implies $x'y'z'=1$. So, it suffices to consider only the case where $xyz=1$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found another proof of the famous Nesbitt's inequality by considering its homogeneity. So, I thought it might be worth sharing it on here for future reference and also to show how homogeneity can be employed to prove a famous inequality by what I've learned today from @Macavity and @SteveKass. I'm going to post it as an answer because it is too long for an edit to my question.

*Theorem:* For $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ we have:

$$ \frac{c}{a+b} + \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} \geq \frac{3}{2} $$

*Proof:*

The LHS stays the same if we substitute $a'=\lambda a$, $b' = \lambda b$ and $c' = \lambda c$.

Suppose that $a'+b'+c'=1$. This implies $\lambda a + \lambda b + \lambda c = \lambda (a+b+c) = 1$, which gives us $\displaystyle \lambda = \frac{1}{a+b+c}$.

In other words, that means for any $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ we can restrict our attention only to the case $a+b+c=1$. Because for any other triple $(x,y,z)$ we can always scale it by $\displaystyle \lambda= \frac{1}{x+y+z}$ to get to that case.

So, from now on, let's assume, Without Loss Of Generality, that $a+b+c=1$.

Now let's prove the inequality. We start by manipulating the inequality from the LHS:

$$ \frac{c}{a+b} + \frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} \geq \frac{3}{2} \iff  \frac{c}{a+b} +1+ \frac{a}{b+c}+1 + \frac{b}{c+a}+1 \geq \frac{3}{2}+3$$
$$ \frac{a+b+c}{a+b} + \frac{a+b+c}{b+c} + \frac{a+b+c}{c+a} \geq \frac{9}{2} \iff \frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+a} \geq \frac{9}{2}  $$

The last statement is correct because we have assumed $a+b+c=1$.

It's trivial that $2=2(a+b+c)=(a+b)+(b+c)+(c+a)$. So, multiplying both sides of the inequality by $2$ we get:

$$((a+b)+(b+c)+(c+a))(\frac{1}{a+b} + \frac{1}{b+c} + \frac{1}{c+a}) \geq 9$$

The last inequality can be checked easily by applying AM-GM inequality or Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Q.E.D.

Comment: Here's another approach to this inequality:

Let $f(x,y,z)=\frac{z}{x+y} + \frac{x}{y+z} + \frac{y}{z+x}$. We show the minimum value of $f$ when $x+y+z=1$ occurs when $x=y=z$.

Suppose not, and WLOG, assume the minimum is $M=f(a,b,c)$, for $a<b$. For small $h>0$, $f(a+h,b-h,c)\approx M+h f_x(a,b,c)-h f_y(a,b,c) = M+\frac{h}{(1-a)^2}-\frac{h}{(1-b)^2}$, which is less than $M$, because $0 \le a < b \le 1$. So $M$ is not the minimum value, and $a$ is not less than $b$ at the minimum. (The derivatives are easy to find if one writes $f(x,y,z)=\frac{z}{1-z} + \frac{x}{1-x} + \frac{y}{1-y}$.)

Comment: @SteveKass: Yes, but that requires calculus which is usually avoided when dealing with easy inequalities like this in 9th grade. It's always nice to see other proofs of the same thing though.

Comment: Good point. One could avoid the need for calculus by showing directly that $f((a+b)/2,(a+b)/2,c) < f(a,b,c)$ when $a < b$. (The first two comments should be in the reverse order - my fault for deleting and reposting instead of editing.)

Comment: Or use the same constraint to say LHS $= \sum \dfrac{a}{1-a}$.  As $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{1-x}$ is convex, Jensen inequality gives $f(a) + f(b) + f(c) \ge 3 f(\frac13) = \frac32$

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to use a restriction to achieve homogeneity, not use homogeneity to achieve a restriction.

Comment: Both of them could be useful depending on the situation. For example, as you can see in my proof of Nesbitt's inequality, the constraint that $x+y+z=1$ allows us to use Jensen's inequality in a fruitful way with little effort. So, if you can find a good restriction like that, it may solve your problem right away.