# Inequality proof for all $x,y,z \gt 0$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

> $$\frac{xy}{z}+\frac{xz}{y}+\frac{zy}{x}\ge x+y+z$$

I want to prove this inequality for all $x,y,z \gt 0$

I started by multiply both sides by $2$, but the factorisation on the left-side was confusing.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576592/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891997/42969 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bxy%7D%7Bz%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7Bxz%7D%7By%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7Bzy%7D%7Bx%7D%20%5Cge%20x%2By%2Bz%24&p=2)

Comment: Please post (formatted) *text,* not screenshots. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I looked at the question but I didn't really understood the solutions, I wanted to work on the solution that I started with, by multiplying both sides by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Am-Gm
$$\frac{xy}{z}+\frac{xz}{y}\geq 2x$$
$$\frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y}\geq 2z$$
$$\frac{xy}{z}+\frac{yz}{x}\geq 2y$$
Q.E.D