# Conditional extreme value of a function

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization

Let $x,y,z$ be the positive real numbers, if $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, then how can we find the minimal value of this function $f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{xz}{y}+\dfrac{yz}{x}+\dfrac{xy}{z}$.

Comment: the answer would be $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: A little more effort goes a long way here. Try to include more workings out, your thoughts on the problem..since you will not learn just by being told.

Comment: I need to find an easy way to prove this problem, which is even understandable by high school students.

Comment: @JetLi What have you tried so far? You have used the calculus tag, so perhaps you might have tried the method of Lagrange multipliers? You should add what you have tried or at least your thoughts on the problem thus far so that other users can tailor their responses to fit your level of understanding, or perhaps use a preferred method of proof.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I don't think L-M is in high school syllabus

Comment: I use the method of Lagrange multipliers, this method is not easy to understand for high school students.

Comment: You can try polar coordinates, which reduces your variables to 2 and drop the condition.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576592/show-that-displaystyle-fracxyz-fracxzy-fracyzx-geq-xyz and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show that, 
$$ \frac{xy}{z}+ \frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y} \ge \sqrt{3}$$ 
This is equivalent to, 
$$ (\frac{xy}{z}+ \frac{yz}{x}+\frac{xz}{y})^2 \ge 3$$ 
Which is same as,
$$ \frac{x^2y^2}{z^2}+\frac{y^2z^2}{x^2}+\frac{x^2z^2}{y^2} + 2(x^2+y^2+z^2) \ge 3 = 3(x^2+y^2+z^2) $$ 
So it suffice to prove that, 
$$ \frac{x^2y^2}{z^2}+\frac{y^2z^2}{x^2}+\frac{x^2z^2}{y^2} \ge x^2+y^2+z^2 $$ 
This is trivial if someone notices inequality, $a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ac $

Elaborating,

Note that, by AM-GM,Following inequalities are true, 
$$\frac{x^2y^2}{z^2}+\frac{y^2z^2}{x^2} \ge 2y^2 $$
$$\frac{y^2z^2}{x^2}+\frac{x^2z^2}{y^2} \ge 2z^2 $$ 
$$\frac{x^2y^2}{z^2}+\frac{x^2z^2}{y^2} \ge 2x^2 $$

Adding gives the desired result. 
Equality when, $x=y=z \implies x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** First, note that $$\dfrac{xz}{y}+\dfrac{yz}{x}+\dfrac{xy}{z}=xyz\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right).$$ Using $a+b+c\geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc}$, try to estimate lower bounds for $xyz$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}$. If you are stuck in the second, consider $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right).$$ Show that the conditions for minimizing $xyz$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}$ can happen at the same time.